# Convert xml file to .doc or .ppt

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some xml files and I have to convert it into doc file dynamically with formatting. What would be best approach? The xml is of following kind

```
What does that mean?</RichText><RichText><Emph>MIKE</Emph>
Look at this... (<Italic>he points, triumphantly</Italic>) Rust.</RichText><RichText><Emph>MRS. MENDEZ</Emph> (<Italic>looking</Italic>)
Looks like dirt to me.</RichText><RichText><Emph>MIKE </Emph>(<Italic>nose in computer, tapping</Italic>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Doc;

namespace Xml2Pdf
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Document doc = new Document();
      doc.LoadFromFile("sample.xml", FileFormat.Xml);
      doc.SaveToFile("test.doc", FileFormat.Doc);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ur code would help me converting xml to doc file but with no formatting. it will show xml tags. although if i save it as htm file, it removes all xml tags but no formatting

Comment: ya and apply formatting written in xml-  {<Italic>he points, triumphantly</Italic>}

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Setting")
        let attr = node.Attribute("name")
        where attr != null && attr.Value == "File1"
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save("output.xml");

Comment: First you have to remove you XML nodes then save this file and SaveToFile as DOC.

Comment: actually i was looking for built in lib or something but i think i better write code myself. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

There should be several ways of creating the formatted MS Office documents. Probably the best option is to use an [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-word-processing-document-by-providing-a-file-name).

There is a good code sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-add-a-new-document-part-to-a-package)

```
// To add a new document part to a package.
public static void AddNewPart(string document, string fileName)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

        CustomXmlPart myXmlPart = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            myXmlPart.FeedData(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. You can try to use XSLT transformations, MS Office Interop, etc. as well